# How to Replace NAs with a mean over a range of rows using a for loop

Tags: python

I am working on a dataset in which I need to replace the missing values given a range of years. See screenshot of dataset below:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QNIHY.png]

Each variable in the dataset should have info for 2011-2019. So essentially, I would require a for loop that goes through my entire dataset and replaces the NAs for specific variable over a 2011-2019 range. For example, any blanks for the Turnover variable would be replaced with the mean of the available data from 2011-2019, and so on for the rest of the variables.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using a pandas data frame. It seems your data is in an excel file. In pandas, you can do it at once and no need to loop over all the rows.

```py
import pandas as pd

dataframe = pd.read_excel("your_filename.xlsx")

# if your data is in csv format

dataframe = pd.read_csv("your_filename.csv")

# fill Nan with 0
df = dataframe.fillna()

# to replace Nan values with mean
df = dataframe.fillna(dataframe.mean())
```